# How to post to facabook wall or send message with image attachement using facebook javascript api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-wall

I would like to post to facabook wall or send message with image attachement using facebook javascript api. Following is my code of 'send' case. Using the code, I can send a message to facebook, but image is not attached(the image is not treated as attachement and displayed small).

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to: id,
    name: 'hoge',
    link: 'http://xx.info/tmp/index.html',
    description: 'hoge',
    picture: 'http://xx.info/tmp/test.jpg'}
);
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended way for the send dialog to work. I do not believe there is a dialog that allows attachments you need to explicitly use API calls.